# Java/SWT mouse hover/click over a column of a tree viewer

Tags: java, hover, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have a `TreeViewer` where some cells are styled to look like links. The tree is filled with content provider and `StyledCellLabelProviders`. I need to know when those specific "link" cells are hovered (so I change the mouse to the hand cursor) and clicked (so I actually do something with those "links").

I failed to find a solution, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Oren

EDIT: More explanation
I have a tree and a treeviewer. There are 4 `TreeColumns` with a `TreeViewerColumn` for each. The data is filled with a content provider, and 2 types of label providers (for simple text and styled text). I need to know when the mouse is clicked on an item in the 4th column and when it hovers over it. When that happens - I need to know the cell it is clicked on, which TreeItem it belongs to, the data in this item, etc.

My problem is I can't figure this out. When I use a mouse listener, or a selection listener, they only work on the first column. I can't "reach" the 4th one.

I cannot change the column order or it won't make sense.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow this approach:

1. attach a `MouseMoveListener` to the Tree
2. determine which `TreeItem` the mouse pointer is over with `Tree.getItem(Point)`.

   For a multi-column tree, `getItem()` will only return an item if the mouse position is within the first column. Either create the tree with the `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` style flag, or use a workaround like this to detmine the item:

   ```
   TreeItem item = tree.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y));
   int x = 0;
   while (item == null) {
     item = tree.getItem(new Point(x, event.y));
     x += 5;
   }
   ```

   It might be necessary to add a further condition (e.g. `x < tree.getBounds().x`) to prevent an endless loop, if no item can be found.
3. once you have the `TreeItem`, you can obtain the element that it shows with `TreeItem::getData`. Be aware that this is an implementation detail of the `TreeViewer` - but I am not aware that there is another way to obtain the element for a given `TreeItem`.

Comment: My TreeItem have 4 columns each, and I don't why, but I create them with a content viewer and I believe each TreeItem in the top level should have a few children (as the content provider shows), but when iterating on them the don't show them. So I am not sure the TreeItem I'll get is correct. I'll try that and update back here.

Comment: Update: I tried it just now, I can get the TreeItem only when hovering over the first column. I don't get it when hovering over the other columns. Any idea?

Comment: @OrenSarid I have updated the answer with what I found out about multi-column trees HTH Rüdiger